# encryption and decryption

Tags: sql-server-2005

how to encrypt the password in asp.net during inserting into database and how to compare it during login?

Comment: What part is causing you trouble, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend

- encrypt in the client (don't roll your own)
- send and store it encrypted in the database as a hash
- on login, encrypt the incoming value and compare against the stored value

There is no need to store plain text in a database.